# Internet explorer 11 file download rename file name

Tags: html, utf-8, internet-explorer-11

Anyone knows why IE11 is renaming my file name that has ’ whenever I download it?
Could it be some character encoding settings?

Attached picture displays the problem. The original file name I save as was Test’s.pdf

[image]

Comment: Yes it's an encoding problem as you suggest. Post your http request/response headers for help resolving.

Comment: Or the method call you used to save this file if any.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve it!

Discovered the bug in my response header as my file name requires encoding

I changed

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

to

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename*=UTF-8''{0}", HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName)));
```